# Maximum stack size in R

Tags: r, stack-overflow

What is the maximum stack size in R? Is it dependent on the machine?

I have read on the R-devel mailing list that one needed to recompile R to increase the max stack size, which makes me think there is a hardcoded limit.

My question is prompted by the following recursive pattern which I use fairly regularly:

```
wait_for_con <- function(..., max_retry = 10) {
  if (max_retry <= 0) {
    stop("Failed to connect")
  }
  tryCatch(connect(...), 
           error = function(e) {
             cat("Could not connect: retrying in 1s")
             Sys.sleep(1)
             wait_for_con(..., max_retry = max_retry - 1)
           })
}
```

I was wondering what order of magnitude of `max_retry` could cause a stack overflow instead of a graceful failure, hence the question.

Comment: Any particular reason to implement this recursively? Why not simply `for(try in 1:max_retry){...break...}`?

Comment: Have you read `help("options")`, in particular regarding the `expressions` option? Recursion is not efficient in R (at least if you use closures) and especially if you `tryCatch`. I would try to avoid it.

Comment: see `?Cstack_info()`

Comment: I think this would be a nice use case for `withRestarts`: https://grokbase.com/p/r/r-help/14c7z5bebp/r-need-help-with-withrestarts

Comment: @Bernhard Sure I could loop, but if you write out what goes in your `{... break...}`, it is not so pretty IMO! I also dislike breaking out of loops for some reason.

Comment: @Roland @ismirsehregal Thanks for the links, they answer my question. `withRestarts` is completely new to me but sounds perfect. My only concern is that it is very R-specific and relatively obscure (since I never came across it in years of R development) so will not be easy for a "standard" developer to maintain. I take your point re efficiency but this loop does not need to be efficient - it typically sleeps for 10s at each iteration!

Comment: Then just use a loop in combination with `try`: e.g., `repeat {res <- try(someAPIcall()); if(!inherits(res, "try-error")) break; Sys.sleep(1)}`.

Comment: @antoine-sac in one respect I am with you, that recursion is often more pretty, but there are languages that are made for recursion and some that are not. Im am trying to convince myself that it is pretty to use every language the way it was meant to be used. Recursion in languages without tail call optimization does not scale well for exactly the reason you stated above. From a prettyness point of view I prefer functions with stable scaling over those that avoid a `break`. YMMV